Where to define "EMR runtime role for cluster" for SageMaker users?
I am encountering this error while attempting to connect to my EMR Serverless Cluster from within the SageMaker Studio Notebook:

Select EMR runtime execution role for cluster
No available EMR execution role found for the cluster. Please provide one in user profile settings.
Please make sure you have run the prerequisite steps.

Where are these roles configured?

The "EMR execution role" can be configured at the following location:
SageMaker // Domain // User Profiles // User // App Configuration // JupyterLab // Amazon EMR Roles


Both of the Execution and Assumable values are blank by default.
These can also be configured at the domain level, but doing so did not make them available to my SageMaker user.

